# rails and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm building a Rails API and would like make it as simple as possible. One thing I would like to accomplish is to receive the JSON as natural as posible. For example:

```
company: {
   name: 'company one',
   addresses: [{ name: 'address1'}, { name: 'address2'}]
}
```

This will not work because the address is a nested model and needs to be name 'addresses_attributes'. I want to get rid of the posfix '_attributes'.

Any idea how to do this? is there any gem?

Comment: Have you looked at rabl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i coded a simple class. Not the best code in the world but it works

```
# nested attributes module
module Api
  module NestedAttributes
    # check for nested attributes
    # transform parameters like this:
    # company: { name: 'test1', address: [{name: 'name1'}]}
    # To
    # company: { name: 'test1', address_attributes: [{name: 'name1'}]}
    def transform params, attributes = []
      apply params, attributes
      return params
    end

    private

    def generate_key key
      "#{key.to_s}_attributes".to_sym
    end

    def apply params, attributes
      case attributes
      when Array
        apply_array params, attributes
      when Symbol
        apply_symbol params, attributes
      when Hash
        apply_hash params, attributes
      end
    end

    def apply_array params, array
       # return the params if the attributes are empty
      return params if array.empty?
      # for each array value
      array.each do |value|
        apply params, value
      end
    end

    def apply_hash params, hash
       # return the params if the attributes are empty
      return params if hash.empty?
      # for each key
      hash.each_key do |key|
        # the new key name
        new_key = generate_key key
        if params.has_key? key
          # delete the key and assigned the value to the new key
          params[new_key] = params.delete(key)
          apply params[new_key], hash[key]
        end
      end
    end

    def apply_symbol params, symbol
      if params.is_a? Array
        params.each { |p| apply_symbol p, symbol}
      else
        if params.has_key? symbol
          new_key = generate_key symbol
          # delete the key and assigned the value to the new key
          params[new_key] = params.delete(symbol)
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

usage:

```
class Test
 include Api:NestedAttributes

 def test
  params = { company: { options: {}}}
  transform params, company: options
  # result => { company_attributes: { options_attributes: {}}}
 end

end
```